# Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: DataType void is not supported.(line 1, pos 0)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am not able to trace the table which contains void data type for columns in the table as I have many tables involved in the Spark-SQL program.I knew some columns having the void data type created in hive table but with stack-trace, I was not able to find which table it was throwing the error.

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
DataType void is not supported.(line 1, pos 0)

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cannot recognize hive type string: void
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$client$HiveClientImpl$$getSparkSQLDataType(HiveClientImpl.scala:860)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$.fromHiveColumn(HiveClientImpl.scala:866)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$getTableOption$1$$anonfun$apply$7$$anonfun$3.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$getTableOption$1$$anonfun$apply$7$$anonfun$3.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:358)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
```

Comment: add proper code what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Adhish - I think this issue is related to - https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/17953.

Comment: Yes. Spark will not recognize the void datatype hive columns and it will throw an error ..I have changed the datatype of hive columns and Spark can read other data types columns than void.